# Declare types for Ramda composed/piped functions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I'm currently trying to use Ramda with Typescript, but i can't find any examples about declaring types for functions expressions created by pipe (or compose) function, below is my code:

```js
interface VersionObject {
    major: number;
    minor: number;
    patch: number;
}

const parseVersionString = pipe(
    split('.'),
    map(unless(isNaN, parseInt)), // btw, ts complain about this parseInt
    zip(['major', 'minor', 'patch']),
    fromPairs
);
```

What i'm trying to do is to declare that `parseVersionString` receives an `string` and returns a `VersionObject`, how could i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two syntax variants which are equivalent:

```
const parseVersionString: (s: string) => VersionObject = pipe(

const parseVersionString: { (s: string): VersionObject } = pipe(
```

Comment: the first example is using an arrow function or am i wrong? could you provide a typescript documentation reference please?

Comment: It's standard TypeScript notation for function types. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#writing-the-function-type

Comment: Although you may enforce a type definition for your function (like that), in a lucky world typescript should just infer a decent type from your pipe() arguments. Unfortunately that usually wont happen because  of how generics work and etcetera.